# Is my cat pooping on bed stress or dominance

Tags: cats

I have 2 cats brother and sister . The female sleeps in my daughters bed every night. Recently we adopted a new cat which has been stressful for all. Yesterday i found a poop in my daughters bed. Would this be the female cat showing dominance and scenting her spot or stress or could it have been the new cat who pooped there?

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) I've marked your question as a duplicate of one that has a great answer already. If your question is different from that one, please edit your question to indicate this.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by stress. My cat did the same thing but she peed in my bed. It happened twice.

I had to take care of the new cat after my mother died. My old cat was afraid of the new one and did pee in my bed, but this happened only two times and never again.

There was some hissing the first week but they became friends and did sleep on the same bed at night.

The two cats had lived in the same house but on different floors, and this made things easier for them (both cats were outdoor cats so they were not strangers to each other).

To make it easier for your cats, you can feed them in different areas in your house until they get to know each other.

Cats do try to show dominance by rubbing against objects and marking the area as "my" territory and sometimes by not hiding the poo in the litter box.

Pooping or peeing around the house can signal stronger and more serious stress in your cat.